# Recognising solar panels using Google Maps?

Tags: raster, google-maps

I need the addresses of all solar panels in Australia recognized on Google Maps  or any other source.

Is there any google solution for that, maybe if I type "solar panels" or if I take some sample to automatically compare with google map?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless someone else has already labelled all solar panels in Australia, bad news, you'll need to undergo a pretty complex process.

Seems [OpenStreetMaps doens't have a category for solar panels or farms](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features).

One possible way of approaching this is:

- Find a provider of good detail ortophotos for Australia. In Europe many countries put this data on the public domain.
- Download all the images at a reasonably detailed zoom level (beware this will take several dozens gigabytes for all Australia).
- Manually find a few hundreds of tiles where solar panels appear.
- Use one of the QGIS image classification algorithms (ie SVM) trying to find other tiles where solar pannels are.